# Twilio get images from whatsapp using functions classic (Node)

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm using Twilio functions (Node) to connect to other service endpoint, messages content works smooth, but the problem I have is because I can't catch image URL to send it.

If I watch "Programmable Messaging"/"Logs/"Message Details" I see image correctly.

[image: Message Details with immage ok]

In "Studio"/"Webchat Flow" on Trigger/incoming message, I set the variables, according with documentation, image URL come in variable trigger.message.MediaUrl0...1...2... But... Variable content it's allways empty. I try with other variables, even I log "trigger" directly:

[image: variables send to my proxy function]

`"{message={EventType=onMessageSent, InstanceSid=***********, Attributes={\"proxied\":true}, DateCreated=2020-10-15T13:47:35.945Z, Index=156, From=whatsapp_********, MessageSid=*****************, Source=API, AccountSid=*******************, ChannelSid=*********, RetryCount=0, WebhookType=studio, To=**********, Body=, ChannelAttributes={status=ACTIVE, long_lived=false, forwarding=true, serviceNumber=whatsapp_txmo0zqebp5s5kmxt5ivs7ofuyhgxpdl, twilioNumber=whatsapp:+TWILIO_NUMBER, from=whatsapp:+MYNUMBER, channel_type=whatsapp, proxySession=****************}, WebhookSid=*************}}"`

What I'm doing wrong?

Kind regads

Comment: Can you confirm you are not using Flex?

Comment: Yes, im using flex, the idea is manage connection to dialogflow through whatsapp, depending the result of conversation, derivate to human contact (Flex).

Comment: When you set your Twilio WhatsApp webhook to a new Studio flow (using the Studio Webhook URL displayed when clicking on the Trigger Widget) in your account, you still don't see Latitude/Longitude? I tested this out and I am receiving those two keys. Note, it looks like you cannot use Flex to send in these WhatsApp location attributes, twilio.com/blog/whatsapp-and-flex-in-minutes-html, as the message is routed through Twilio Proxy.

Comment: It's not about location, is about images sended from Whatsapp.

I will try with URL, let's see what I got.

Comment: Same issue. Images are not currently supported with the out of the box components of Flex using MMS or WhatsApp.

Comment: When I use a function directly I catch image URL. So, I have two approaches to solve the problem:


1 - Get (some way, somehow) image URL through API.

2 - Manage connection with Flex via API, but, I don't know how to do it, I need to investigate.